# How can I use java to simulate login

Tags: java, web, httpurlconnection

I want to use httpurlconnection class to simulate login a website. I try to 
capture packet to get the request header and I put it all to my program. But this code can't get cookie from server.

```
    String username = "。。。。。。;
    String password = ".。。。。";
    String param = "username="+username+"&pwd="+password+"&usertype=xuesheng&Submit=+%B5%C7%C2%BD+";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)urlx.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host","jwc.ecjtu.jx.cn:8080");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","74");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control","max-age=0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","http://jwc.ecjtu.jx.cn:8080");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","1");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("DNT","1");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Referer","http://jwc.ecjtu.jx.cn:8080/jwcmis/assess/");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

This is the key code that I send to server.
What should I do that I can simulate login successfully? What else code should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason that I didn't get cookie is that the website I post will redirect link, I didn't set setInstanceFollowRedirects(false). I get wrong response. So I didn't get cookie

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read about [CookieHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html)

There is an example of solution of simulate login in java http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

Comment: sorry,these days I do some homework in school...  My matter is that I submit the same as thing as browser, but server didn't give me the same response as the browser's receive